# Shutdown Hook with windows-scripting-host

Tags: vbscript, wsh, shutdown-hook

This [link](http://www.bigresource.com/Tracker/Track-vb-MjQNB6lXIl/) discusses how a shutdown hook can be implemented using VB. Now my question is, can something like that be done using Windows Script Host/windows scripting host?

I would very much appreciate your input; maybe include some code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about other scripting languages such as PowerShell or Perl, but in VBScript/JScript there doesn't seem a way to do this.

First of all, Windows Script Host doesn't provide access to Windows API so you can't intercept the `WM_ENDSESSION` and `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` Windows messages (as suggested in the article you mentioned) from VBScript/JScript.

There's the WMI [`Win32_ComputerShutdownEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394101.aspx) event though, which occurs when a computer shuts down, but [you can only receive this event from remove computers](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/0d39fe27-1355-4e4f-a7cf-2bcb9a475b3b). When the local computer shuts down, the script is terminated before the event is delivered.